# Android: Doing all my drawing on a SurfaceView; what's the proper way of making sure my drawing conforms to any screen size?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, surfaceview

I'm making an app (a game, to be exact) where each activity uses a SurfaceView for the UI. All of the drawing is done through onDraw. I am also designing this to use no Bitmap assets, so everything that is drawn is produced directly by the app. I'm trying to design the app in such a way that it can easily be viewed on any screen size.

So here's how I'm accomplishing this: I'm doing my testing on a Galaxy S4, which has a screen size of 1080x1920. In the constructor for each activity, the width and height of the current screen are calculated and stored as ints "w" and "h" (the app is already locked in portrait). Then, whenever anything needs to be drawn onto the screen, I multiply the desired dimension (as seen on my 1080x1920 screen) by either w or h, and then divide by 1080 or 1920. Since I'm not using any Bitmap assets, I never need to worry about pixelated images or anything this way.

This gets the job done, but seems like a bit of a roundabout way of doing it. I figured there would be a better framework for getting this done, and I'm worried that these big calculations are eating into my drawing time (running at 30FPS can get a little jerky).

Is this is the customary way of doing it, or is there a better way out there?

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, try not to allocate memory in onDraw.  That's probably what is causing your stutters, not simple calculations.

Comment: I don't think I am. Any Bitmap that is created is done so once in the Activity constructors, and altered through its canvas if need be. Isn't that the right way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you aren't creating other smaller objects (like RectF for example) either for maximum performance.

Comment: I still have to do some testing to see exactly where the jerkiness is coming from... I am doing a lot of calculations involving trigonometric functions (from Math) in my thread.run(), which updates thirty times a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple yet effective way to do it, you can declare all your sizes in a dimen file for each specific density/size, as you usually do for layouts e.g:

> values/dimens.xml <--- With default sizes
>
> values-sw600dp/dimens.xml <-- Tablets sizes
>
> (etc...)

Now before you start drawing, load all the values in your program only once, maybe onCreate of your drawing activity, using the following command:

> float someItemSize = Context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.some_itemSize)
>
> etc...

That way, you let the operating system do the pixels conversion for you, you should do it only once and most important, this will give alot of flexibility to your code because you will be able to change sizes from xml files without even touching your actual code, hence, the customization should be easier as well as future changes...

Hope it helps!

Regards!

Comment: Cool, thanks. I had a feeling I'd have to play around with XML to accomplish this. And for sizing drawings vs. text... I want to use dp for drawings and sp for text, correct?

Comment: That is correct, the method i showed in my answer will give you the pixel values accordingly, so you don't have to worry for any conversion...

Answer (score 0):

There are two considerations: screen size and screen aspect ratio.  If you simply scale everything to match the display, you will appear stretched a bit if you put a 4:3 device next to a 16:9 device.

You generally have two options for dealing with the aspect ratio: you can letterbox / pillarbox the output (which is fine for movies, but looks kinda lame for an app), or you can recognize that your output isn't always proportionately the same, and adjust the layout to fit nicely on the screen.

As far as size matching goes, when using a SurfaceView you can actually use a single size and then let the hardware scaler handle the rest.  For an example of this, see the "Hardware scaler exerciser" in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  I put a [demo video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpRaD-ij2xc), though it's a bit hard to evaluate after getting rinsed through screenrecord + youtube.  What you're seeing is the same couple of shapes rendered onto a Surface whose size has been set to an arbitrary value, and then scaled up to match the display.  This is most obvious on the final setting, where it's drawing on a 106x64 surface.

With this, you could size your assets for 720p and always draw them the same way, and let the scaler deal with the stretching.  See also [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html).